# Can the memory allocated by the malloc function be freed after the type of the pointer pointing to the memory is transformed?

Tags: c

Recently, I am trying to understand how to efficiently free the memory space allocated by the malloc function in the C language. And I have got some ideas about this, but I am not sure whether they are right or wrong. So, I come here to ask for some suggestions.

For example:

Fisrt, I define a Structure, i.e. demo. And use demo to define a structure pointer, i.e. demo *demo_pointer = NULL. Then, using malloc function to allocate a piece of memory space to this pointer, i.e. demo_pointer = (demo *)malloc(sizeof(demo)). Normally, to free this memory space, I need fisrt to do "free(demo_pointer)", next to do "demo_pointer = NULL".

But, if I use "free((char *)demo_pointer)", can I free the allocated memory?

If this can work, I think I could define a function to do this:

```
void Free(void **p)
{
    free(*p);
    *p = NULL;
    return;
}
```

Thus, to free the allocated memory space, I only need to do "Free(&demo_pointer)". Does it work?

Thanks for your kind suggestions!

Comment: have you looked have `free` function is defined? https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free

Comment: You don't have to set the pointer to `NULL` to free memory. Or do you want to just automate this?

Comment: It's unclear why you want *"free((char *)demo_pointer)"*

Comment: There's no _magic_. `malloc()` returns the address of a block of contiguous bytes. As long as that address is not _mangled_ before being passed to `free()`, you can cast to your heart's content...

Comment: In C the pointer doesn't have a type per-se, the value it points to does.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to ensure that the pointer variable is set to NULL after the call to `free()`, a simpler solution might be to simply define a macro.

```
#define myFree( p ) do { free(p); p = NULL; } while(0)

/* code */

char *foo = malloc( 80 );
/* omitting test for success */

/* code */

myFree( foo ); // 'foo' will now be set to NULL
```

Comment: Macros are not my favorite but in this case it seems a good solution... so have one...

Comment: @SupportUkraine I agree about the "not favourite", but the language is _rich_ and there is a time and place for everything... Thanks, btw `:-)`

Comment: @Simon_Fuys When you've had a chance to review the offered answers here on SO, it's nice to "accept" the one that best serves your needs... This helps others find answers to their questions when faced with similar problems (and bolsters the "reputation" of the answer's author.)

Comment: Ah... The spineless DV moron is back on the prowl... Pathetic...

Answer (score -1):

Yes is the answer to the question in title, and to the question  whether passing the address of `demo_pointer` to your `Free` function would free the memory or not.

> But, if I use "free((char *)demo_pointer)"

Not fatal but `free`'s signature accepts `void *`.

I would recommend you to read more about memory allocation and de-allocation functions. Especially the functions prototype as what they accept as arguments/parameters and what do they return.

> Normally, to free this memory space, I need fisrt to do
> "free(demo_pointer)", next to do "demo_pointer = NULL".

`demo_pointer = NULL` is not mandatory. The `demo_pointer` is already freed by `free`. This is just a cosmetic way of indicating that the memory pointed by `demo_pointer` was freed.

This helps in cases where the `demo_pointer` is getting accessed later in the program, there `demo_pointer` can be checked:

```
if (!demo_pointer) {
   /* do something */
} else {
   /* do something else */
}
```

If your concern is efficiently freeing the memory, then `free` just does that. Just make sure that the previously allocated memory/address is not mangled up.

And if you want all the freed up addresses to point to `NULL` value by default then the `Free` function in your question is just fine. You could get rid of the `return`.

Answer (score -1):

The question asks:

*But, if I use `free((char *)demo_pointer)`, can I free the allocated memory?*

**The short answer is: No**

Explanation:

When it comes to `malloc` and `free` the important thing is **the value of the void pointer** returned by `malloc`. When you later call `free` you need to pass a void pointer with the **exact same value**.

Now the C standard specifies that if a void pointer is converted to any other pointer type and back to void pointer, the resulting value will be equal to the value of the original void pointer.

So code like

```
T* var = malloc(...);  // Implicit conversion: void pointer to T pointer
free(var);             // Implicit conversion: T pointer to void pointer
```

is fine. First a void pointer is (implicit) converted to a T pointer and then the T pointer is (implicit) converted back to a void pointer which is used as argument for `free`. That is exactly the conversion steps that the standard guarantee to give identical values.

However the code

```
demo* demo_pointer = (demo *)malloc(sizeof(demo));
free((char *)demo_pointer);
```

is doing these pointer conversions:

```
void pointer --> demo pointer  // explict cast (btw: not needed in C)
demo pointer --> char pointer  // explicit cast
char pointer --> void pointer  // implicit conversion
```

The C standard does not guarantee that this sequence of pointer conversion will result in the final void pointer being equal to the initial void pointer. Consequently, the final void pointer can't be used when calling `free`

It will probably work on any real world system but the standard has no such guarantee.

Regarding your function:

The prototype is

```
 void Free(void **p)
```

so the function expects a **pointer to pointer to void**

When calling it like

```
Free(&demo_pointer)
```

the argument is a **pointer to pointer to demo**

These are incompatible types so the **function is incorrect**.

Compiling this code

```
struct demo *demo_pointer = malloc(sizeof *demo_pointer);
Free(&demo_pointer);
```

with "gcc -Wall -Wextra" also gives warning like:

```
main.cpp: In function 'main':
main.cpp:40:10: warning: passing argument 1 of 'Free' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   40 |     Free(&d);
      |          ^~
      |          |
      |          struct demo **
main.cpp:16:18: note: expected 'void **' but argument is of type 'struct demo **'
   16 | void Free(void **p)
      |           ~~~~~~~^
```

that tells you that it's the wrong thing to do.